# can't run a shell script(which runs a gui installer after a while) with both sudo and kdesu in openSUSE

Tags: sudo, opensuse

I'm trying to install a software which comes with a shell script to install, and I need to run this in su because of some drivers it installs.

When I try to run this shell script with sudo:

```
➜  lab  sudo ./xsetup 
_xsetup: cannot connect to X server
```

And this is the error message I get in a dialog window when I try to run it with kdesu:

```
Cannot execute command ' ./xsetup'.
```

Thanks.

Btw, if anyone's interested, the software I'm trying to install is [Xilinx](http://www.xilinx.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `kdesu` can't properly locate your script, use full path instaed of relative and check if script is executable. `sudo` can't find proper X Dispaly, may be because DISPLAY variable is not correctly set. Can you run gui applications from console, that you use, without sudo?